# Open Address Book and select a phone number of a contact which is having multiple numbers in iOS

Tags: objective-c, abaddressbook

I am developing a dialer application in XCode. In my application there is a button to pickup phone numbers from AddressBook. When a user click on that button I need to open the original iOS AddressBook and the user must be able to select a contact. If the contact has multiple numbers saved, the user should be able to select the number he need. After selection the number should be displayed in a UITextField. I have seen the same option in Skype Application.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why must it be done with the contacts app, do it inside your app.

Comment: Hello Wain... Using contacts app we can do that... I have seen it in some ios applications. We have an android version of the same application. In that one we have done like this. So I need to do it in the same way in ios version as well.

Comment: People shouldn't think that Android and iOS must work in the same way - they should work in the way a user of that device would expect, and they expect different things...

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible to my knowledge. You'll have to fetch the contacts yourself and present them. My guess is that the apps you have seen that you think does this is simply just skinning the views as in the iOS Contacts app.

Have a look at https://github.com/Alterplay/APAddressBook for a convenient and easy-to-use wrapper around the Contacts API.